# What tribe was Barak from?

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes, shoftim--book-of

Please bear with the odd question.

About a year ago, I was in the middle of writing an essay on some of the shoftim that have less background information written about them in Sefer Shoftim. Unfortunately, the part I wrote about Barak got erased at the time. I have a note I left saying that somehow I'd gotten into my head that Barak may have been from the Tribe of Levi. Yes, I know the most common interpretation of the verse " וַתִּשְׁלַח, וַתִּקְרָא לְבָרָק בֶּן-אֲבִינֹעַם, מִקֶּדֶשׁ, נַפְתָּלִי" - "And she sent and called Barak the son of Abinoam out of Kedesh-naphtali" ([Shoftim 4:6](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0704.htm)) is that the Tanach makes him out to be of the Tribe of Naftali, but there's also a midrashic text that makes this a bit ambiguous:

[Yalkut Shimoni on Nach, 42:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.42.5?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

"מכל השבטים יצאו שופטים ומלכים ומשבט שמעון לא קם לא שופט ולא מלך בשביל החטא שעשה זמרי בשבטים, ללמדך כמה חמורה הזנות. עתניאל בן קנז משבט יהודה. אהוד משבט בנימין. דבורה וברק מהר אפרים ומקדש נפתלי. גדעון משבט מנשה ואבימלך בנו אחריו, תולע בן פואה משבט יששכר. יאיר הגלעדי מחוות יאיר משבט מנשה. וכן יפתח מיושבי גלעד. אבצן מבית לחם יהודה. אלון משבט זבולון. עבדון בן הלל משבט אפרים. שמשון משבט דן. עלי ושמואל משבט לוי, ומבנימן יצאו מלכים. ומיהודה מלכים. ומאפרים ירבעם. וממנשה יהוא בן נמשי. אבל שמעון לא העמיד לא שופט ולא מלך בשביל עון הזנות, לפיכך נתנה תורה ברית מילה בערוה שיהא יראת המקום מונעת מלעשות החטא."

Translation:

"From all the Tribes there rose judges and kings and from the Tribe of Shimon there didn't rise not a judge nor a king..." -

Then the midrash proceeds to list off seemingly judges and kings from all the tribes, except not really. The midrash does not cite rulers from the following tribes (besides Shimon): Reuven, Gad, Asher.

Furthermore, the language the midrash uses is strange: For most of the leaders, it outright says so and so was from such and such a tribe. But in the case Dvorah and Barak, it merely states they were from places in the territories of those tribes and doesn't explicitly state they were of those tribes.

Therefore, I was wondering if anyone knows of any source that states something along this line of thought I had? Not specifically that Barak was from Levi, but that he may not have been from Naftali?

Comment: It also says וכן יפתח מיושבי גלעד. אבצן מבית לחם יהודה

Comment: I would have assumed Naftali as his own tribe would probably have been the first to follow him. Thus, since the army is from *the tribe of Naftali and the tribe of Zevulun*, the first one mentioned is most probably the one he was from.

Comment: I don't see much hope here for not being from Naftali, but you'd probably enjoy the discussions at length in the journal HaOtzar v 28 and 29 about the Shoftim's tribes and the Midrash you cite

Comment: @sabbahillel the supposed answer to that (still from the little note I left myself, but also unsourced) is that Barak may have been a Levite who lived in a Levite city that was in the Naftali territory, but not actually a Naftalite himself. He had good ties with his Naftalite neighbors.

Comment: @Heshy you're right about Ivtzan. But to me the וכן about Yiftach seemed to be referring directly to the previous shofet, Yair the Giladi, on whom it specifically says of Menashe.

Comment: I wonder if you might be confusing him with Shamgar, where (as with Barak) it's not so clear that he was a shofet - he's not explicitly named as one - and there are sources, although I can't find them now, that he was from Levi.

Comment: @Meir no not at all. Like I said, I was writing an essay on all of the judges that lacked background info, Shamgar included. In fact, as long as we're on the subject, there are different opinions on what tribe he was from. Some say Levi, some say Shimon (which goes with the fact that he wasn't exactly a judge) and some even say he was a ger. I'm also open to this being a completely ludicrous notion.